# Multiple condition between two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I am working on a variant calling Format(.vcf) file. I am separating genotype Allele from individual genome data and calculating the chance of having the specific disease. Based on my analysis I need to implement a condition like :
I have two different panda data frame which are extracted from .vcf file

1. Diseases

| SNP | EfectSize | MinorAlleFrequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rs05 | 0.32 | 0.09 |
| rs012 | 0.5 | 0.20 |
| rs02 | 0.8 | 0.29 |

2.IndividualSNPs

| SNP | cola | colb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rs02 | 0 | 1 |
| rs03 | 1 | 1 |
| rs12 | 0 | 0 |

my condition will be like: if number 1.dataframe (Diseases) column 'SNP' is match with number 2. dataframe (individualSNPs) column 'SNP'. then I will check from individualSNPs dataframe cola and colb column.

```
if( cola=0 and colb=0):
  score = MinorAlleFrequency* effectSize (from datafram Diseases of matched row)

if( cola=0 and colb=1) or (cola=1 and colb=1):
  score = (1 - MinorAlleFrequency)* effectSize (from datafram Diseases of matched row)

if( cola=1 and colb=0):
  print("genotype unavailable")
```

then the score value will save in a CSV file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: These are multiple questions, but you should start by taking a look at `pandas.merge` or `DataFrame.join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could start by merging your dataframes so that you get a new dataframe with columns from both dataframes, and only keep rows from the `Diseases` dataframe (column SNP) that exist in the `IndividualSNPs` dataframe (column SNP). It would be like :

```py
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.merge(diseases_df, individual_snp_df, on="SNP", how="inner")
```

Then as you do not have that much conditions, you could do :

```py
indexes = new_df[(new_df["cola"] == 0) & (new_df["colb"] == 0)]
new_df["score"].loc[indexes] = new_df["MinorAlleFrequency"] * new_df["EffectSize"]
```

And repeat it with your variations (I guess your second condition, can be resumed to `colb == 1`) :

```py
indexes = new_df[new_df["colb"] == 1]
new_df["score"].loc[indexes] = (1 - new_df["MinorAlleFrequency"]) * new_df["EffectSize"]
```

Finally, let the rest empty with a `NA` can be a better solution than putting a string ("genotype unavailable") in a float column.

Comment: I am getting 'DataFrame' 'objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed'  error when using indexes as key and score as a value.

Comment: Actually you are right ! I edited my answer with a solution that now works

Comment: Solved it. I think it will...new_df.loc[indexes, "score"] = (1 - new_df["MinorAlleFrequency"]) * new_df["EffectSize"]....thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
newDf = IndividualSNPs[Diseases["SNP"] == IdividualSNPs["SNP"]][["cola","colb"]]

score = np.where(((newDf["cola"] == 0) & (newDf["colb'] == 0)), (Diseases["MinorAlleFrequency"])*(Diseases["EffectSize"]), np.where(((newDf["cola"] == 0)&(newDf["colb"] == 1)) | ((newDf["cola"] == 1) & (newDf["colb"] == 1)), (1 - Diseases["MinorAlleFrequency"]) * (Diseases["EffectSize"]),print("genotype unavaible")))
```

Comment: Maybe something like this can solve that. Of course parentheses must match!